# Flutter - Agora Livestreams ends for everyone when a Cohost exits the livestream

Tags: flutter, dart, live-streaming, agora.io

I'm having an issue where if an audience member that has been promoted to Cohost exits the active livestream, the stream is ended for everyone.  I only want the host that started the livestream to be able to end it, not a cohost.

I have the following code for changing the role from audience to Cohost:

The host sends a message to the audience member they want to promote to cohost --

```dart
   widget.client.sendMessageToPeer(groups['id'].toString(), AgoraRtmMessage('Hey $username would you like to join this live?', 1, false)).onError((error, stackTrace) => print("Error: $error")) ;
```

The audience member receives the message and hits enter to accept the promotion to cohost. With the following config:

```dart
 await _engine.setClientRole(ClientRole.Broadcaster);
    await _engine.enableVideo();
    client.addOrUpdateChannelAttributes(widget.channelName, [], true).onError((error, stackTrace) => print("Error: $error \n Stacktrace:$stackTrace"));
    setState(() {
      coHost = true;
      }); 
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

That works properly for changing the role of audience member to broadcaster(cohost).

However, when the cohost exits the active livestream it's terminated for everyone.  I have the following code that's executed when the cohost exits the active stream:

```dart
                print("Owner ID IS : $ownerId");
                await client.sendMessageToPeer(ownerId, AgoraRtmMessage('I am leaving', 2, false)).whenComplete(() async{
                  print("Done");
                 await _engine.setClientRole(ClientRole.Audience);
                 client.addOrUpdateChannelAttributes(widget.channelName, [AgoraRtmChannelAttribute("TEST", "1")], true);
               print("CHANNEL NAME IS :${widget.channelName}.");
```

I also get the following log output when the Cohost exits the live:

```
I/flutter ( 2510): Remote Video State is: VideoRemoteState.Stopped
I/flutter ( 2510): Remote Video Reason: VideoRemoteStateReason.RemoteMuted
I/flutter ( 2510): Remote Video State is: VideoRemoteState.Decoding
I/flutter ( 2510): Remote Video Reason: VideoRemoteStateReason.RemoteUnmuted
D/*WEBRTCN*( 2510): VideoRenderAndroid dtor
I/flutter ( 2510): userOffline: 1854772710
I/flutter ( 2510): Remote Video State is: VideoRemoteState.Stopped
I/flutter ( 2510): Remote Video Reason: VideoRemoteStateReason.RemoteOffline
```

I don't understand what's missing as I believe I'm following the reference docs correctly.

I am using the following for reference : https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/faq/host_set_role

Comment: Inside the `onMessageReceived` callback can you try running the `onAttributesUpdated` callback

Comment: Hi @Meherdeep Thakur this is the following config I have on the onMessageRecieved callback on the host side _client.addOrUpdateChannelAttributes(channelName, [AgoraRtmChannelAttribute("TEST", "1")], true);
       widget.channel.onAttributesUpdated([AgoraRtmChannelAttribute("TEST", "1")]);                                                       Though when I do this I get no output to the console. Is there a specific channel attribute I should be passing ? It wasn't to clear on the docs what should be passed on the AgoraRtmChannelAttribute parameter

Comment: ```
Map<String, String> map1 = {
  "key": "xxx",
  "value": "true",
};

Map<String, String> map2 = {
  "key": "xxx",
  "value": "true",
};

await _rtmClient.addOrUpdateLocalUserAttributes([map1, map2]);
```

The correct implementation would be something like this.